# SDL2.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl

Hi I am following an SDL tutorial, but when I try to run the program I get this error :

```
The program can't start because SDL2.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem
```

None of the other answers to this question have helped me. I have tried placing the SDL2.dll file in the Debug folder with the .exe file, in the project root folder, and in the folder with the .cpp files

I don't think my code matters for this issue, but here it is anyway.

main.cpp

```
 #include "MainGame.h"
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    MainGame mainGame;
    mainGame.run();

    return 0;
}
```

MainGame.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>

enum class GameState {PLAY, EXIT};

class MainGame
{
public:
    MainGame();
    ~MainGame();

    void run();
private:
    void initSystems();
    void gameLoop();
    void processInput();
    void drawGame();

    SDL_Window * _window;
    int _screenWidth;
    int _screenHeight;
    GameState _gameState;
};
```

MainGame.cpp

```
#include "MainGame.h"
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void fatalError(std::string errorString)
{
    std::cout << errorString << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter any key to quit....";
    int tmp;
    std::cin >> tmp;
    SDL_Quit();
}
MainGame::MainGame()
{
    _window = nullptr;
    _screenWidth = 1024;
    _screenHeight = 720;
    _gameState = GameState::PLAY;
}


MainGame::~MainGame()
{
}

void MainGame::run()
{
    initSystems();

    gameLoop();
}

void MainGame::initSystems()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    _window = SDL_CreateWindow("Game Engine", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, _screenWidth, _screenHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    if (_window == nullptr)
    {
        fatalError("SDL Window could not be created!");
    }

    SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(_window);
    if (glContext == nullptr)
    {
        fatalError("SDL_GLContext could not be created!");
    }

    GLenum error = glewInit();
    if (error != GLEW_OK)
    {
        fatalError("Could not initialize glew");
    }

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}

void MainGame::gameLoop()
{
    while(_gameState != GameState::EXIT)
    {
        processInput();
        drawGame();
    }
}

void MainGame::processInput()
{
    SDL_Event e;

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) 
    {
        switch (e.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                _gameState = GameState::EXIT;
                break;
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                std::cout << e.motion.x << " " << e.motion.y << std::endl;
                    break;
        }
    }
}

void MainGame::drawGame()
{
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(_window);
}
```

I'm using visual studio 2015.

Comment: Does your `sl2.dll` has the same bittness, as your project?

Comment: That worked, thank you.